# Extending spring-hateoas Link class after constructor deprecation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

In my application I have class that extends spring-hateoas `Link` class:

```
class LinkWithAdditionalField extends Link {
    private final String additionalField;

    LinkWithAdditionalField(String href, String rel, String additionalField) {
        super(href, rel);
        this.additionalField = additionalField;
    }

    ...
}
```

that adds additional field to model representation:

```
"_links" : {
    "self" : {
        "href": "https://example.com/...",
        "additionalField": "additionalValue"
    }
}
```

and it is used this way:

```
LinkWithAdditionalField link = (LinkWithAdditionalField) entityModel.getLinks().toList().get(index)
String additionalField = link.getAdditionalField();
```

It is working, however version `1.1` of spring-hateoas deprecated [`Link(String, String)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/Link.html) constructor (and recommends using static method `Link.of(String, String)`) .

Is there any recommended way (some new API that I am missing?) to do this, that allows adding additional fields to links, after upgrading Spring to latest version?

Using composition (and static method `Link.of(String, String)`):

```
class LinkWithAdditionalField {
    private final Link link;
    private final String additionalField;

    LinkWithAdditionalField(String href, String rel, String additionalField) {
        this.link = Link.of(href, rel);
        this.additionalField = additionalField;
    }

    ...
}
```

won't work in my case because of casting:

```
LinkWithAdditionalField link = (LinkWithAdditionalField) entityModel.getLinks().toList().get(index)
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into the source code of `org.springframework.hateoas.Link`, the static method `Link.of(href, relation)` just calls the deprecated constructor `Link(href, relation)`.

```java
public static Link of(String href, String relation) {
    return new Link(href, relation);
}
```

So you can stick to your original code.

Comment: I don't want to rely on deprecated API, right now this constructor is public, but in future `spring-hateoas` maintainers may make it private, and then I would have the same problem again. Plus compiler treats any warning as error and I do not want to make exception for this constructor